# Is this amount of disk IO expected with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-ec2

I am running MySQL 5.5.34 on an Amazon EC2 micro instance with EBS (elastic block storage).  The instance has been running for around 10 days and according to Amazon I've accumulated around 8.5 million IO requests.  This seems abnormally high considering there is one 2 MB database used for Wordpress.  I've used the site very lightly, just some editing in the backend, no live traffic.  Here is the memory available:

```
# free -t
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        615376     531848      83528          0       2296      58864
-/+ buffers/cache:     470688     144688
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:      615376     531848      83528
```

If I have around 83 MB of free space in memory why would MySQL not keep the 2 MB database there?  The reason I suspect MySQL for the high IO activity is when I run `iotop` mysqld always shows having the most activity.  Here is my config:

```
[mysqld]

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
query_cache_size=64M
key_buffer_size=64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=2M
table_cache=1024
join_buffer_size=4M
thread_cache_size=128
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64MB

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Is there any way besides `iotop` to know if MySQL is using memory vs disk?  Does anything in my configuration look wrong for my system?

**Update**: Ran query from answer below and output was:

```
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Storage Engine | Data Size            | Index Size           | Table Size           |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| InnoDB         |             1.469 MB |             0.625 MB |             2.094 MB |
| Total          |             1.469 MB |             0.625 MB |             2.094 MB |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

In /var/lib/mysql:

df -h .

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  3.8G  4.1G  49% /
```

ls -l

```
total 28688
drws--S--- 2 mysql arithmakids     4096 Dec  5 05:07 arithmakids
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       18874368 Dec 13 23:03 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        5242880 Dec 13 23:03 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        5242880 Dec 13 23:03 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql           4096 Apr 18  2012 mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql              0 Dec 13 22:54 mysql.sock
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql           4096 Apr 18  2012 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql           4096 Apr 18  2012 test
```

Based on this what would be good settings for my.cnf?

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL Disk USage

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(
B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",
CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',
SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/
POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size"
FROM (SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,
SUM(index_length) ISize,SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') AND
engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,(SELECT 2 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;
```

This will tell you exactly how much diskspace (in GB) MySQL is actually using for tables.

Please see my other post [CPU usage on RDS instance monotonically increasing with no change to query volume](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20813/cpu-usage-on-rds-instance-monotonically-increasing-with-no-change-to-query-volum/20814#20814) on additional Storage Engine diskspace queries.

You also need to do this

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
df -h .
ls -l
```

Take note of ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and other files. You will also see how much disk is free for the disk holding `/var/lib/mysql`

Please run `ls -l /var/log/mysqld.log` to see if the log is too big.

## MySQL Memory Usage

You have

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
query_cache_size=64M
key_buffer_size=64M
```

That's 192MB. Since you have a lot of other defaults, you only have about 100 or 131 max connections. I recommend [downloading MySQL Administrator for Free](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) and watching memory usage in other aspects.

## Epilogue

Please look over my Amazon RDS posts for other ideas

- [Should I increase max_connections in AWS RDS t1-micro for MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41829/should-i-increase-max-connections-in-aws-rds-t1-micro-for-mysql/41842#41842)
- [When should I think about upgrading our RDS MySQL instance based on memory usage?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25840/when-should-i-think-about-upgrading-our-rds-mysql-instance-based-on-memory-usage/25870#25870)

Comment: Updated original question with additional info

Comment: any suggestions based on the additional info above?

Comment: Are you running any type of monitoring (SQLYog, Munin, Nagios, phpMyadmin, etc) ???

Comment: No, not running any monitoring.  Just want to understand if the amount of IO I'm seeing is expected based on my memory and database size or if something is mis-configured.  It seems to me like something is wrong if a tiny database is causing that much IO.

Comment: Is mysql the only thing running in the EC2 instance ? Are you running other things, like memcached ?

Comment: No memcached.  The instance came pre-loaded with Virtualmin, PHP, MySQL and Apache.  I used Virtualmin to create one site and installed Wordpress on that site.  Would you recommend using memcached for my setup or should I first make sure my.cnf is configured correctly for my box?

Comment: Can you recommend good settings for my.cnf based on the given info or do you need more information?

Comment: Try installing the Performance Schema (P_S) on your system. It will give you various metrics - although the version for 5.5 is not as good as for 5.6. Use MySQL Workbench as previously recommended to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet was pretty telling:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       18874368 Dec 13 23:03 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        5242880 Dec 13 23:03 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        5242880 Dec 13 23:03 ib_logfile1
```

Looks like you are under constant write load. What are you doing with this db?